# Why increase of array alignment degrades performance?

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization

I am trying to increase aligment of array in synthetic test from 16 to 32 and performance degrades from ~4100ms to ~4600ms. How higher alignment can harm performance?

Below is the code which I use for testing (I am trying to utilize avx instructions here). Build with `g++ test.cpp -O2 -ftree-vectorize -mavx2` (I have no support of avx512).

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using Time = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;
using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;

template <typename Duration>
auto as_ms(Duration const& duration) {
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration);
}

static const int repeats = 10000;

struct I {
    static const int size = 524288;
    int* pos;
    I() : pos(new int[size]) { for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) { pos[i] = i; } }
    ~I() { delete pos; } 
};

static const int align = 16; // try to change here 16 (4100 ms) / 32 (4600 ms)

struct S {
    static const int size = I::size;
    alignas(align) float data[size];
    S() { for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) { data[i] = (i * 7 + 11) % 2; } }
};

void foo(const I& p, S& a, S& b) {
    const int chunk = 32;
    alignas(align) float aprev[chunk];
    alignas(align) float anext[chunk];
    alignas(align) float bprev[chunk];
    alignas(align) float bnext[chunk];
    const int N = S::size / chunk;
    for (int j = 0; j != repeats; ++j) {
        for (int i = 1; i != N-1; i++) {
            int ind = p.pos[i] * chunk;
            std::memcpy(aprev, &a.data[ind-1], sizeof(float) * chunk);
            std::memcpy(anext, &a.data[ind+1], sizeof(float) * chunk);
            std::memcpy(bprev, &b.data[ind-1], sizeof(float) * chunk);
            std::memcpy(bnext, &b.data[ind+1], sizeof(float) * chunk);
            for (int k = 0; k < chunk; ++k) {
                int ind0 = ind + k;
                a.data[ind0] = (b.data[ind0] - 1.0f) * aprev[k] * a.data[ind0] * bnext[k] + a.data[ind0] * anext[k] * (bprev[k] - 1.0f);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    S a, b;
    I p;
    Time start = Clock::now();
    foo(p, a, b);
    Time end = Clock::now();
    std::cout << as_ms(end - start).count() << std::endl;
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != S::size; ++i) {
        sum += a.data[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

Checking if cache causes the problem:

```
valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./a.out
```

alignment = 16:

```
==4352== I   refs:      3,905,614,100
==4352== I1  misses:            1,626
==4352== LLi misses:            1,579
==4352== I1  miss rate:          0.00%
==4352== LLi miss rate:          0.00%
==4352== 
==4352== D   refs:      2,049,454,623  (1,393,712,296 rd   + 655,742,327 wr)
==4352== D1  misses:       66,707,929  (   66,606,998 rd   +     100,931 wr)
==4352== LLd misses:       66,681,897  (   66,581,942 rd   +      99,955 wr)
==4352== D1  miss rate:           3.3% (          4.8%     +         0.0%  )
==4352== LLd miss rate:           3.3% (          4.8%     +         0.0%  )
==4352== 
==4352== LL refs:          66,709,555  (   66,608,624 rd   +     100,931 wr)
==4352== LL misses:        66,683,476  (   66,583,521 rd   +      99,955 wr)
==4352== LL miss rate:            1.1% (          1.3%     +         0.0%  )
```

alignment = 32

```
==4426== I   refs:      2,857,165,049
==4426== I1  misses:            1,604
==4426== LLi misses:            1,560
==4426== I1  miss rate:          0.00%
==4426== LLi miss rate:          0.00%
==4426== 
==4426== D   refs:      1,558,058,149  (967,779,295 rd   + 590,278,854 wr)
==4426== D1  misses:       66,706,930  ( 66,605,998 rd   +     100,932 wr)
==4426== LLd misses:       66,680,898  ( 66,580,942 rd   +      99,956 wr)
==4426== D1  miss rate:           4.3% (        6.9%     +         0.0%  )
==4426== LLd miss rate:           4.3% (        6.9%     +         0.0%  )
==4426== 
==4426== LL refs:          66,708,534  ( 66,607,602 rd   +     100,932 wr)
==4426== LL misses:        66,682,458  ( 66,582,502 rd   +      99,956 wr)
==4426== LL miss rate:            1.5% (        1.7%     +         0.0%  )
```

Seems like the problem is not in cache.

---

Checking that problem is not in Turbo Boost.

alignment: 16 --> 32

with Turbo Boost **enabled**: ~4100ms --> ~4600ms

with Turbo Boost **disabled**: ~5000ms --> ~5400ms

Comment: 'Performance degrades from ~4600ms to ~4100ms' is a contradiction in terms. This is an *improvement.*

Comment: @EJP Sorry, that was a mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: The code uses a lot of stack memory. Increasing the alignment will make it use even more. Growing the stack might take some time.

Comment: @BhavinChirag what's the variance of your measurements?

Comment: @BoPersson I thought that it is only single addition of constant known at compile time to the stack pointer. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user2079303 The variance is less than 100ms.

Comment: For both versions, GCC generates quite different machine code: https://godbolt.org/g/WNQj72 (from line #107 in diff view, suggest to maximize the diff pane). Can you try Intel compiler? Is it the same with `-O3`?

Comment: @DanielLangr According to [link](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) page 108, to achieve full utilization of YMM vector registers the requirement is to align array by 32. So it is wise for compiler to generate better code with that alignment. But for some reason the result is opposite: it generates code that works longer.

Comment: @Bhavin - I'm mostly guessing. Using Visual Studio instead of g++, I have to move `S a, b;` out of main to avoid a stack overflow. After that there is no difference in the timing.

Comment: @DanielLangr gcc with -O3 gives the following results: 4700ms for aligment 16, 4300ms for alignment 32. I am trying to avoid -O3 because it generates a bloat of code, which badly utilizes instruction cache.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior when `p.pos[i] == 0`. Anything can happen.

Comment: @SergeRogatch `i` goes from `1`, so `p.pos[i] == 0` should never happen in the code.

Comment: @SergeRogatch Fortunately, I am not accessing p.pos[0] which equals to zero when others not.

Comment: Do you disable Turbo Boost while testing?

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy I disabled Turbo Boost through bios and got ~5000ms for align = 16, ~5400ms for align = 32.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I did some measurements with GNU g++ 6.4.0 and Intel icpc 18.0.1 on Haswell E5-2680v3. All the times were very consistent with deviations of few milliseconds only:

1. `g++ -O2 -mavx2 -ftree-vectorize` `align=16`: 6.99 [s]
2. `g++ -O2 -mavx2 -ftree-vectorize` `align=32`: 6.67 [s]
3. `g++ -O3 -mavx2 -ftree-vectorize` `align=16`: 6.72 [s]
4. `g++ -O3 -mavx2 -ftree-vectorize` `align=32`: 6.60 [s]
5. `g++ -O2 -march=haswell -ftree-vectorize` `align=16`: 6.45 [s]
6. `g++ -O2 -march=haswell -ftree-vectorize` `align=32`: 6.45 [s]
7. `g++ -O3 -march=haswell -ftree-vectorize` `align=16`: 6.44 [s]
8. `g++ -O3 -march=haswell -ftree-vectorize` `align=32`: 6.44 [s]
9. `icpc -O2 -xCORE-AVX2` `align=16`: 3.67 [s]
10. `icpc -O2 -xCORE-AVX2` `align=32`: 3.51 [s]
11. `icpc -O3 -xCORE-AVX2` `align=16`: 3.65 [s]
12. `icpc -O3 -xCORE-AVX2` `align=32`: 3.59 [s]

Conslusions:

- For GCC, `-march=haswell` was faster than `-mavx2` and, for `-march=haswell`, practically insensitive to optimization level and alignment.
- ICC provided much much lower runtimes / higher performance than GCC.
- For ICC, proper alignment helped, but only slightly.
- Interestingly, ICC with higher optimization level provided higher runtime, but this might be attributed to larger program size and therefore more instruction cache misses.

In my experience, ICC is generally much better than GCC, at least as for vectorization. I haven't studied the generated machine code, but one can do this using, e.g., Godbolt to understand why is ICC such superior in this case.

Comment: Also it is possible to see difference in gcc flags with command `diff -u <(gcc -mavx2 -Q --help=target | grep enabled) <(gcc -march=haswell -Q --help=target | grep enabled)`

Comment: It is abolutely weird now. Actually I checked that with Intel Core i5-7200U 2.50GHz. The conclusion might be to use desktop/server processor to do performance measurements.

Comment: Yes, you result is very predictable, but unfortunately mine is not.